# Change style of a particular element in a mx:Tree

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I want to change the style (put some text in italic) in one part of a mx:Tree. Like this

```
var data:Array = [
 { label: "one", children: [
   { label: "a"},   { label: "b"},   { label: "c"} 
  ]}
];
```

how I can show only the element with label c in italic?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom item renderer that checks for a given condition in your data (`data.label == "c"` in your case) and shows the text in italic depending on the outcome. If you did it in MXML, since you cannot bind style properties, a way of achieving it would be:

```
...
<mx:Label text="{data.label}" visible="{data.label == 'c'}" includeInLayout="{data.label == 'c'}" fontStyle="italic"/>
<mx:Label text="{data.label}" visible="{data.label != 'c'}" includeInLayout="{data.label != 'c'}"/>
...
```

where ... stand for the surrounding item renderer markup